# Upgrading TFS 2010 build definitions to TFS 2013 build template

Tags: tfs, build-definition, build-process-template

I have ported over all of my build customizations from TFS 2010 to the new TFS 2013 build process template. What would be the best approach to upgrade the old build definitions to the new template while retaining the settings (i.e. configurations to build, project, ect.) from the old one?

Answer (score 0):

If your arguments are still the same, you should be able to open your existing definition and just apply the new template. All of your original settings should remain intact

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I make the template change, the settings for the custom activities are brought over, but the settings for Project, Configurations, etc. are not retained.

Comment: yes I found lots of issues, variables gone, overridable targets gone.